# How can I select a value from a database using Ruby and SQLite3?

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlite

I am having trouble returning a single value from a database using SQLite3 and Ruby.

A bit of context: I have a table of people and I would like to be able to query the database and get back the first name of someone in that table. I am using Rubymine with the SQLite3 gem.

When I run this code:

```
name = @db.execute <<-SQL
    SELECT firstname FROM tbl_people WHERE email_address = '#{email_address}';
  SQL
  puts name
```

I get the following ouput:

```
{"firstname"=>"james", 0=>"james"}
```

When really the output I am expecting is:

```
james
```

If anyone can even point me in the right direction here it would be very much appreciated.

Cheers,
James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The execute() method creates a resultset, not just a single scalar value. You need to process the resultset to get the single value out of it.

```
name.each do |row|
    puts row['firstname']
end
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! This helps so much, I thought it would be something simple like this but didn't really understand what I was doing, this explained it brilliantly! I would have up voted your answer but I don't have enough reputation :(

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to return the first value of the first row of a result set, and discard all other values and rows.  The [Database#get_first_value](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sqlite3/1.3.13/SQLite3/Database#get_first_value-instance_method) is what you want.

Also, for security you shouldn't inject strings into your SQL; allow the library to handle that for you.

```
query = "SELECT firstname FROM tbl_people WHERE email_address = ?;"
name = @db.get_first_value query, email_address
puts name
```